# jQuery File Upload Using Siebel OUI in IE11 Does Not Work

Tags: jquery-file-upload, siebel

When I attempt to drag and drop a file onto a Siebel attachment list applet, IE11 is opening the file instead of uploading/creating new record in the applet.  I can see the drop zone tag "Copy" when I hover over the applet but when I drop the file it gets opened in the same browser window.  Expected result should be that the file is uploaded and added to the applet in Siebel without any prompts.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the text "Move" with an arrow pointing to the right shows up when I hover the file object over the applet.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the browser was running in elevated mode for the dedicated client.  The drag and drop does not work for local dedicated client unless you are running IE in non-elevated mode.  Also, the new button on our applet was invoking "NewRecord" method instead of "NewFileAttachment" as it does in OOB Siebel account attachment applet.  So I changed MethodInvoked for the New button to "NewFileAttachment" and ran the dedicated client in regular mode and drag and drop works beautifully :)